# Checking how many characters are in a String (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find out how many of the characters in my array are in my string password.
It errors in the console saying, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. I'm trying to port this code from java but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
var password = "h@llo";

var list = [];

list.push('!');
list.push('@');

var charcount = 0;

for (var ch : password.toString){

    if(list.contains(ch)){
        charcount ++;
    }

}


$("#console").append(charcount + "<br/>");
```

Comment: You should just use `password.length`

Comment: `for (var ch : password.toString){` is not valid JavaScript. How did you come up with this syntax?

Comment: @FelixKling Looks like Java's enhanced for-loop, except `toString` isn't being called.

Comment: I recommend to read a tutorial about the basic statements in JavaScript, e.g. http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html . It's not too hard to find documentation about how loops work.

Answer (score 1):

Your description was unclear, but I've edited my code and should fit your expectations now.

```js
var password = "h@llo";
var elements = ['h', '@'];
var count = 0;
password.split('').forEach(v => elements.some(c => c == v) ? count++ : null);

console.log(`There are ${count} elements from elements array inside password string.`);
```

Using `Array#filter`.

```js
var password = "h@llo";
var elements = ['h', '@'];
var count = password.split('').filter(v => elements.some(c => c == v)).length;

console.log(`There are ${count} elements from elements array inside password string.`);
```

Comment: I want it to return 1 because there is one of the characters listed in my array in the string, I don't know what your thinking of.

Comment: @Leon Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's `for(var ch of ...)` not `for(var ch : ...)`. Try this:
2. `password` is already a string so `toString` is useless
3. Arrays don't have a function called `contains`, use `indexOf` instead!

Try this:

```js
var password = "h@llo";

var list = [];

list.push('!');
list.push('@');

var charcount = 0;

for (var ch of password){
    if(list.indexOf(ch) != -1){
        charcount ++;
    }
}


console.log(charcount);
```

Comment: Or just remove `toString()` since `password` is already a string.

Comment: @FelixKling and also don't loop over a string to count it's chars :)

Comment: It is `for (a in b)`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: No, that wouldn't iterate over the characters.

Comment: In my java I use password.charToArray(), What would be the equivalent in javascript.

Comment: @Dekel: Well, depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @Leon: There is no need for something like that.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen `for in` return indexes not characters!

Comment: var list = [];
    
    list.push('!');
    list.push('@');
    
    var charcount = 0;
    
    for (var ch of password){
        
        if(list.indexOf(ch)){
            charcount ++;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    $("#console").append(charcount + "<br/>");   THIS line of code returns the length of my string and not how many @'s it has in it, but it doesn't error

Comment: @Leon it's `indexOf(ch) != -1` not just `indexOf(ch)`! as -1 is true!

Comment: Leon, just to be clear your code does not return the length of the string, but the number of characters it contains that are in your list.

Comment: Yea thats what I want.

Comment: *"Arrays don't have a function called `contains`"* - But they do now have a method called [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do it:

With a `Set` and `split('')` (equivalent of Java's `charToArray`), and `filter`:

```js
var password = "h@llo";
var list = new Set(['!', '@']); // make it a set for direct access
var charCount = password.split('').filter( ch => list.has(ch) ).length;
console.log(charCount);
```

and with a regular expression:

```js
var password = "h@llo";
var re = /[!@]/g; 
var charCount = password.match(re).length;
console.log(charCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Leon it's indexOf(ch) != -1 not just indexOf(ch)! as -1 is true! – ibrahim mahrir 28 mins ago

This worked, I don't really know whwat != -1 means though so does anyone know of a doc that explains that or could explain it now?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Inequality_(!)